# TAR harmful operation mode

Tags: tar, corrupt, recover

Do you know why this happens and how can I recover my original file?

I needed to tar and compress a file called `foo`. So I did:

```
tar -cvf foo foo.tar.gz
```

As you can see, there is an error: `foo.tar.gz` must be in place of `foo`. This, of course, is a novice error. But, why tar didn't show me an alert of this? What tar did was to overwrite and corrupt my original file so I cannot read it now! Imagine if `foo` was an important and unique file!

Additionally, I know that one cannot tar only one file but just compress. Anyway...

Thank you everybody,

Moti

Comment: I once lost days of coursework because I did `gcc program.c -O2 -o program.c`, and couldn't understand why `./program` gave me the old result :-( (In my defence that was back when CVS was state-of-the-art RCS.) It happens because we told our tools to do the wrong thing and they happily did. You likely can't get your file back in that case, no. There might be some corner cases where the foo inode was held open elsewhere and so the new data gets written to different disk but I'd doubt it.

Comment: I see :( . Thank you for your response. I will see if there is a way to evite to fall in this situation again. Maybe I can make an alias of tar, I mean, like the very known technique of the command rm: `alias rm='rm -i'`. Do you know a similar technique for the `tar`command?